# Как отправить данные на два почтовых ящика?

Tags: php, email

На странице есть форма отправки данных. Если я не ошибаюсь, за это отвечает этот код:

```
$args = array(
  'key' => 'какой-то ключ,
  'message' => array(
    "html" => null,
    "text" => 'Заявка с сайта сайт.ru. '.print_r($_POST,true), 
    "from_email" => 'какая-то почта',
    "from_name" => 'Заявка',
    "subject" => 'У вас новая заявка',
    "to" => array(array('еmail'=>'еще почта'))              

  )
);

mail($args['message']['to'][0]['email'],$args['message']['subject'],$args['message']['text']);
```

Пробовал добавить еще один ящик, чтоб и туда уходила информация:

```
"to" => array(array('еmail'=>'еще почта', 'доп. почта'))
```

и так:

```
"to" => array(array('еmail'=>'еще почта', 'еmail'=>'доп. почта'))
```

Или надо целый массив создавать для этого? Типа:

```
$args = array(
  'key' => 'какой-то ключ,
  'message' => array(
    "html" => null,
    "text" => 'Заявка с сайта сайт.ru. '.print_r($_POST,true), 
    "from_email" => 'какая-то почта',
    "from_name" => 'Заявка',
    "subject" => 'У вас новая заявка',
    "to" => array(array('еmail'=>'еще почта'))              

  )
);

mail($args['message']['to'][0]['email'],$args['message']['subject'],$args['message']['text']);

// второй массив
$args-second = array(
  'key' => 'какой-то ключ,
  'message' => array(
    "html" => null,
    "text" => 'Заявка с сайта сайт.ru. '.print_r($_POST,true), 
    "from_email" => 'какая-то почта',
    "from_name" => 'Заявка',
    "subject" => 'У вас новая заявка',
    "to" => array(array('еmail'=>'еще почта'))              

  )
);
```

Comment: Что вы уже пробовали сделать для решения проблемы? Что именно не получилось?

Comment: Пробовал:"to" => array(array('еmail'=>'еще почта', 'доп. почта'))
и так:
"to" => array(array('еmail'=>'еще почта', 'еmail'=>'доп. почта'))

Comment: Тут больше 380 символов не умещается, поэтому дал ссылку - там все написано.

Comment: Все, что относится к вопросу, должно быть в самом вопросе. Ссылки могут служить только _дополнением_.

Comment: "Что вы уже пробовали сделать для решения проблемы? Что именно не получилось?" Пробовал отредактировать код, письмо на второй ящик не приходит.

Comment: Хорошо, куда надо было поставить ссылку?

Comment: Еще раз: ссылка может служить только **дополнением**. Вся информация, относящееся к вопросу должна быть описана в **самом вопросе**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то Вам вместо

```
"to" => array(array('еmail'=>'еще почта', 'доп. почта'))
```

нужно написать

```
"to" => array(array('еmail'=>'еще почта, доп. почта'))
```

чтобы по ключу email брался весь список ящиков, на которые надо делать рассылку

Comment: К сожалению, такой вариант пробовал, не сработало. И так не работает "to" => array(array('еmail'=>'еще почта', 'доп. почта'))

Comment: Попробуйте вместо mail($args['message']['to'][0]['email'],$args['message']['subject'],$args['message']['text']); написать mail('еще почта, доп. почта',$args['message']['subject'],$args['message']['text']); тем самым проверите, срабатывает ли у вас в принципе отправка на несколько ящиков

Comment: Спасибо вам, Константин! Это сработало!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй записать строку для email в виде одной строки в соответствии со стандартом.

```
'еmail'=>'Someone <someone@any.com>; Other Person <Other_Person@mail.ru>; And One More <OneMore@and.com>'
```